# Fillbetween y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I use fillbetween to fill between a shape and the y-axis? I found this post: [How to use fill between package along the y axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406865/how-to-use-fill-between-package-along-the-y-axis), but I couldn't make heads or tails of it. I'm just trying to a pretty simple example where I fill in between y=0 and y=4. Here is all I have so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-4, ymax=4, ylabel=$y$,
  xmin=-4, xmax=4, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
]
    \addplot[domain=-10:10,blue,name path=A] {x^2}; % actual curve
    \addplot[name path=B, blue, domain = 1:4] {0}; % “fictional” curve
    \addplot[gray!50] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=1:4}]; %filling
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I know this only fills in the x-axis, but I do not know a simple way to get it to work on the y-axis. Pretty new to LaTex so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear to me whether you want to shade the regions below or above the curve, so I provide both options.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[set layers,
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=-4, ymax=20, ylabel=$y$,
  xmin=-4, xmax=4, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
]

    \addplot[domain=-10:10,blue,name path=A] {x^2}; % actual curve
    \addplot[name path=B, draw=none, domain = -4:4] {0}; 
    \addplot[name path=C, draw=none, domain = -4:4] {4}; 
    \pgfonlayer{axis background}
    \clip(-2,0) rectangle (2,4);
        \fill [
            gray!50,
            intersection segments={of=A and B,
                sequence={A0 -- A1 -- B*[reverse]},
            },];
        \fill [
            orange!50,
            intersection segments={of=A and C,
                sequence={A1 -- B*[reverse]},
            },];
    \endpgfonlayer
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]